# Query for making Sales Invoice iReport

Tags: mysql

http://www.4shared.com/photo/q95NaCKo/satack.html
this is a image where i create a table like this

Question:
I want create a Report, but before that i must create a Query where i take field2 from many tables. From my image..where word with underline is primary key...

There're have six's table where not null..before, i try this query...

```
create view view_si as 
select sellheader.NoBukti as  nobukhead,mssell.NoBukti,       
mssell.KodeBarang,mssell.Qty,
mssell.Satuan,mssell.Harga,mssell.Qty, 
mssell.Harga as Qtyharga 
from sellheader 
join mssell on sellheader.NoBukti = mssell.NoBukti 
group by sellheader.NoBukti
```

but it can't work with my mind...

i want the result like this..

http://www.4shared.com/photo/FTbZzX2K/capture.html

i've tried JOIN ON but on table sellheader only a row..beside that mssell have 2 rows..
if i join them. it become 1 row..

Comment: what you mean with can't work ? error or the result is not correct ?

Comment: anyway, please rearrange your questions

Comment: We want to help you but: 1) explain a little bit your datamodel and your tables. 2) Tell us what do you expect to retrieve. 3) tell us exactly which is the error